# PDF generated has font issue after window server upgrade

Tags: windows, pdf, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2003, acrobat

After I have moved from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008 R2, the PDF font issue was encountered.

The description of the issue:

Using Window Server 2003, crystal report is used to export the report to PDF. Using the object tool option in PDF to select the string, we can see the string below contains in one box. (*not enough reputation to post images)

'abcde'

However when Window Server 2008 is used, a different string is produced.

'abcd' 'e'

As you can see, the string is separated into 3 boxes when windows server 2008 is used. Hence, I am unable to use a simple java program to read the string due to the added spaces (about one pixel difference).

The crystal report engine has not been changed. Hence, I susupect that it is due to the window server font issue, but have no idea how to rectifty this issue.

Hope someone has a solution to this problem. 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Examine the fonts used in the PDFs by opening them with Adobe Reader and using Properties->Fonts. If they differ, determine why. Possibly you are missing a font on the new server that is used and installed on the old server.

Comment: Thank you Kevin for the comment. I checked both PDFs, and both of their fonts are "Times-New-Roman-Bold"

Comment: Hi Kevin, I used another crystal report software, SAP 2013 SP01 instead of using VS 2005 and the issue is resolved!